# Check if a facebook user can post in his friends wall or not

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As far as I've done research I could come up with use of can_post in fql query. Now how can I find out can_post value of the user. I'm using php-sdk and have taken the permission to post to friend's wall but since if friend has disabled posting on his wall it would return an exception which would make the script stop. So, if I could use this can_post value to check if he can post before posting.

Comment: Not sure how this works with PHP, but maybe you can try something like: $facebook->api('/me/permissions/','get') --- This should return a JSON string with all the permissions you have. You can change '/me' to a facebookUserId to check the permissions your app has of other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the **[can_post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)** field using fql and that will return either true or false. So if friend has disabled posting on his wall, in that case also **can_post** field would return false. So that would aid in wall posting depending on can_post...

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did as u said and it worked for me. To be honest it made the script a bit slow as it had to check for each friends can_post status. The script I used was:
    $check = $facebook->api(array(
       "method" => "fql.query", 
       "query"  => "SELECT can_post FROM user WHERE
uid=".$selectedid
        ));